# Jack eats up his dinner

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

Eat up your dinner.
Eat your dinner up.

> *Jack eats up his dinner.*
>
> *Jack eats his dinner up.*

Could we say in these way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say either one, but the word *up* gives the sentence a colloquial feel. It sounds like something a parent would say to (or about) a child.

I might tell my son:

> Jack, you should eat up your broccoli.

but I would probably **not** say to my boss:

> Sir, you should eat up your sandwich.

instead, I'd leave the *up* out:

> Sir, you should eat your sandwich.

---

This kind of question really makes me empathize with English learners! Here's why: with the verb *eat*, adding the word *up* to make a phrasal verb makes the sentence sound more colloquial. But with the verb *finish*, adding the word *up* seems fine.

So, while I have a hard time imagining myself telling my boss:

> Katie ate up her lunch.

I have a much easier time imagining myself telling my boss:

> Katie finished up her report.

Even when I'm talking about food!

> Sir, I'll send you that spreadsheet right after I finish up my lunch.

If you look carefully in dictionaries, though, you can find small hints about such distinctions. If you look at Macmillan, under [**eat up**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/eat-up), it says:

> **eat up** (*phrasal verb*) `MAINLY SPOKEN` to eat all of something

whereas under **[finish up](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/finish-up)**, it says:

> **finish up** (*phrasal verb*) same as *finish*

Collins has an interesting note under [**eat up**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eat-up) as well:

> **eat up** (*verb*) to eat or consume entirely: `often used as an exhortation to children`

Answer (score 2):

Jack eats up his dinner.

Jack eats his dinner up.

There's no difference in meaning.  You can use "up" either before or after a noun phrase. However, you use "up" after a pronoun, not before.   For example: Mom has prepared dinner for me and wants me to eat it up. You cannot say .....eat up it.

Comment: Look at this, "Eat up your dinner". Written by Eric Hill. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD7hvWtb4ns
time 3:20

Comment: @user73963 - I think there's a big difference between "eat up _your dinner_" or "eat up _your soup_" and "eat up _it_". The ones with the nouns sound fine, but the one with the pronoun sounds off.